# Why to use Readonly fields after C# 6?

Tags: c#

I'm having a dilemma with Get-Only props vs `readonly` after we can assign Get-Only right away like this `string X { get; } = "dd"` .
So the question is: Why do we ever want to favour using `readonly` field in a `class` after C# 6 instead of using Get-Only property?

We can do this:

EX 1.

```
private readonly IService _service;
public A(IService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

BUT we can also do this:

```
private IService _service { get; }
public A(IService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

Both scenarios can only be initialized in ctor and can be used only within a class.

We can do those (from ctor as well):

EX 2.

```
private string SomeString { get; } = "s";
private readonly string SomeString2 = "s";
```

I cannot inherit `readonly` field but I can inherit Get-Only prop, which might be confusing to distinguish from the inherited prop but only when you have a capital naming convention for private props, if you use `_prop` you are fine. So more flexibility here.

We can also have:

EX 3.

```
public readonly string Field;
public string Field2 { get; }
```

And those are working the same except for minor thing for dev awareness - he cannot tell on the spot if the `Field2` was not inherited.

I used to write DTO's like this:

EX 4.

```
public class DTOProp
{
    public string Field1 { get; }
    public string Field2 { get; }
    public string Field3 { get; }

    public DTOProp(string field1, string field2, string field3)
        => (Field1, Field2, Field3) = (field1, field2, field3);
}
```

Currently like this

```
public record DTORec(string Field1, string Field2, string Field3);
```

But never seen like this:

```
public class DTORo
{
    public readonly string Field1;
    public readonly string Field2;
    public readonly string Field3;

    public DTORo(string field1, string field2, string field3)
        => (Field1, Field2, Field3) = (field1, field2, field3);
}
```

We can write the hypothesis for `readonly` fields that can look like that -

*When You use C# 6+ You can safely replace `readonly` fields with Get-Only properties with no side effects*

and it seems completely valid to me.

After we replace the `readonly-ies` we end up with a more predictable way of writing a code without losing the meaning of the code and well as changing the behaviour.

I understand that the backing field will be created and it might have some performance impact but to optimize the application to that point we will probably have 99% more important issues in other places.
The only thing that might be an "issue" is the problem I mentioned in EX 3 but it probably evens out with time to respond to a PR comment "why not Get-Only prop here?".

PS. Tried to find a similar question. Didn't actually find the answer I was looking for

Comment: This seems like a redux of [the usual property vs field argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property). The existence of a new shorthand for read only properties with initializers doesn’t change the recommended uses - it just makes it take one line where it used to take two.

Comment: @Mitch: I think that the use cases for *private, read-only* fields/properties are sufficiently distinct from "regular" fields and properties that a separate question is justified.

Comment: A read-only, auto-implemented property is still a `readonly` field, but now you have to use a method (the `get` accessor method) to read it, so unless you can guarantee aggressive inlining will be respected, you're now calling a method to get the field value, even from within the class. It still does the job, but it's just not the same thing anymore. Your hypothesis suffers the can/should question. Yes, you can use read-only, auto-implemented properties, but should you? Probably not.

Comment: @Heinzi - I disagree, but I’m not voting to close, just throwing my two cents out there. The normal advice about properties vs fields is about encapsulating logic - insulating consumers from changes in implementation.  ”readonly” private props don’t give this benefit, add extra syntax, and are potentially performance impacting.

Comment: As a side note, not all get-only properties are auto-implemented, so your post inadvertently is referring to a broader class of properties that don't fit into this mold. You should familiarize yourself better with these terms, and the underlying implementation details, before attempting to drive paradigm changes.

Comment: @Mitch How can you change the Get-Only prop value after its initialized? You would have to change the actual logic. You cannot do this: `private string _name { get => M1(_name); } = "aa";` and you also cannot do this `private string _name2 { get => M1(_name2); }` when field is initialized in ctor. If you do this `private string _name3 { get => M1(SomeOtherField); }` you can as well just remove `readonly` if we are changing the actual logic

Comment: @madreflection Sorry but not sure what you mean. I have both cases as examples for initialization - take a look at EX 1. and EX 2 and the question is about Get-Only and `readonly` (only those)

Comment: Asking for list of use cases is generally off-topic on SO. In this case it looks like @Pawel you want to discuss coding style (whether private property used as backing filed for a public property is a good idea or not) which I believe is opinion-based (there is no strong reasons to pick one or another).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The initial question "Why do we ever want to favour using readonly field in a class after C# 6 instead of using Get-Only property?" I didn't want it to be opinion based. The question might have been asked like "Why do we ever want to favour using IQuerable<T> over IEnumerable<T>?". Actually there are already two anwers, one is in short "Because you want to have encapsulated readonly ref field" which I think is a pretty good answer the current coding standards is also a pretty good answer since the intent of dev is also important.

Comment: @Pawel, I don't understand the question "How can you change the Get-Only prop value after its initialized?" since the whole point of a `get`-only property is that you can't change the value.

Comment: @Mitch I'm referring to encapsulation you mentioned "The normal advice about properties vs fields is about encapsulating logic - insulating consumers from changes in implementation". As far as I can see when you change the `readonly` to `get`-only you will have the same encapsulation. After the value is initialized we cannot really change the value same as with `readonly`. So actually I can't see the importance of the argument about adding extra "benefits" unless you change the actual behavior of code execution (like intermediate function for init in ctor).

Comment: @Pawel, yeah. That’s what I’m  saying. Fields are the canonical “default”, so why add the complexity (both syntactically and technically) when there is no benefit?  The argument is that you should use a property to encapsulate logic, *and otherwise default to using a field*.

Comment: @Mitch imo complexity has not been added, in fact, we are making the code more consistent since there will be props everywhere and currently there are mixtures of `readonly` and `get`-only all over the place. If someone from your team would create a DTO based on `readonly` (EX 4.) you would probably put a comment in PR since it's inconsistent with other DTOs (even though it reduces complexity). I believe this is the same case

Comment: @Pawel, questions which are primarily opinion based are off topic for StackOverflow. It is an empirical statement that a property is more syntactically and technically complex than a field since it necessarily includes accessors.  If you have specific circumstances that make it make sense, go for it.

Comment: @Mitch Statement "When You use C# 6+ You can safely replace `readonly` fields with Get-Only properties with no side effects"  Rikki Gibson response ~"you can't because of ref". Where is the opinion here?

Comment: @Pawel, the question asked was “*why* use readonly fields [vs get-only properties]” - which is opinion based apart from truisms like “to encapsulate logic”.  Asking “Are get-only properties and readonly fields interchangeable/indistinguishable” has factual answer (“no, they are not interchangeable - even though they may have similar uses”).

Comment: @Mitch You are simplifying a bit here. The question asked was "Why do we **ever** want to favour using `readonly` field in a class after C# 6 instead of using Get-Only property?" - which has technical answer - and was followed with the hypotesis "When You use C# 6+ You can safely replace `readonly` fields with Get-Only properties with **no side effects**" - which also touches upon technical analysis (not speculations and opinions). I could also claim your question to be opinion-based because you can interchangeably use `readonly` and `get`-only in DTOs - it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Opinion based question would be "Why Windows Terminal looks better than Command-Line?" There is no technical answer for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a ‘ref’ to a field, but you can’t for a property. If the field is of a struct type, this might be relevant to reduce copying.

Comment: Yup, that's a valid point. I actually never seen `ref readonly` field in production code though.

Answer (score 3):

> *When You use C# 6+ You can safely replace readonly fields with Get-Only properties with no side effects*

From a technical point of view, you might be right (except for the `ref` edge case mentioned by Rikki in his answer).

However, after two decades of reading and writing C# code, I have the impression that, in idiomatic C#, it has become customary

- to use fields for `private` data, unless you have a good reason to use a property instead, and
- to use properties for `public` data, unless you have a good reason to use a field instead.

Thus, if you use a property for private data *without an obvious reason*, you make your code a bit harder to read for others, since you violate one of the unwritten conventions of the language. It's a "mental speed bump" when reading your code: People stop to wonder *why* you used a property, when a field would have served the same purpose.